# Proving $2((a+b)^4+(a+c)^4+(b+c)^4)+4(a^4+b^4+c^4+(a+b+c)^4)=3(a^2+b^2+c^2+(a+b+c)^2)^2$ in another way?

Tags: algebraic-numbers, algebraic-equations

How do I prove the following identity without expanding both sides directly.
$$2((a+b)^4+(a+c)^4+(b+c)^4)+4(a^4+b^4+c^4+(a+b+c)^4)\\=3(a^2+b^2+c^2+(a+b+c)^2)^2$$

I expanded both sides directly and it is true. However, I was hoping there could be another way to prove it, like that of Candido's identity which could be proved using diagrams.

Comment: We can then use the identity: $$\bigg(\frac{-p+q+r+s}2\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{p-q+r+s}2\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{p+q-r+s}2\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{p+q+r-s}2\bigg)^2=p^2+q^2+r^2+s^2$$ and substitute: $p=a$, $q=b$, $r=c$ and $s=a+b+c=x$ to follow that $$3(a^2+b^2+c^2+x^2)^2=3\times\Bigg\{\bigg(\frac{-a+b+c+x}2\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{a-b+c+x}2\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{a+b-c+x}2\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{a+b+c-x}2\bigg)^2\Bigg\}^2$$ and given that $x=a+b+c$ we would have lots of cancelling out. That is, $$3(a^2+b^2+c^2+x^2)^2=3\big((b+c)^2+(c+a)^2+(a+b)^2\big)^2$$ as your LHS. Now it should be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Why do this by hand?

*Mathematica*:

`Simplify[2 ((a + b)^4 + (a + c)^4 + (b + c)^4) +  4 (a^4 + b^4 + c^4 + (a + b + c)^4) ==  3 (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + (a + b + c)^2)^2]`

(* True *)

Comment: Thanks, it is because I don't know how to use Mathematica.

Comment: Just copy and paste the above into WolframAlpha (free, online):  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2+%28%28a+%2B+b%29%5E4+%2B+%28a+%2B+c%29%5E4+%2B+%28b+%2B+c%29%5E4%29+%2B++4+%28a%5E4+%2B+b%5E4+%2B+c%5E4+%2B+%28a+%2B+b+%2B+c%29%5E4%29+%3D%3D++3+%28a%5E2+%2B+b%5E2+%2B+c%5E2+%2B+%28a+%2B+b+%2B+c%29%5E2%29%5E2

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to prove that $F=G$ where $F$ and $G$ are symmetric homogeneous 4th degree polynomials in three variables. Fully expanded, such a polynomial is in the form $$A\left(a^4+b^4+c^4\right)+B\left(a^3(b+c)+b^3(a+c)+c^3(a+b)\right)\\+C\left(a^2bc+b^2ac+c^2ab\right)+D\left(a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2\right)$$

Imagine the above equals your $F$, and you do not yet know $A,B,C,D$. Substitute four points of the form $(a,b,c)$. You would get four linear equations in $A,B,C,D$. As long as you are not very unlucky, these four equations are independent and linear algebra will tell you the values of $A,B,C,D$.

But the same could be said with $G$ on the right side. And if your solutions for $A,B,C,D$ match, then you may conclude $F=G$.

Really, as long as you trust that you pick four triples $(a,b,c)$ that lead to independent equations, as long as you verify that your left side equals your right side at those four triples, it establishes that $F=G$.